# После перезагрузки windows 10 не сохраняются изменение на диске, что делать?

Tags: windows-10

Можно удалить все программы на компе либо установить, после перезагрузки изменения пропадают.
windows 10 стоит.
Откат не работает, исправление диска тоже.
Второй HDD работает нормально.
В чем дело как фиксить ума не приложу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Shadow defender установлен?

Comment: Нет, не установлен

Comment: Надо без ```/r```

Comment: Сработало но проблем не обнаружено

Comment: Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth на этом тесте синий экран и надпись: system server exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сдал по гарантии получил новый диск, видимо ошибка не лечится.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в командной строке выполнить sfc /scannow && Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth && Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup && ChkDsk /r

И что значит пропадают, полностью во всех папках или только системные? И еще вопрос, это у вас случайно не виртуальная машина?

Comment: system server exception
такая ошибка на синем экране когда начинаешь активно память использовать(во время диагностики тоже)
"Пропадают" например удалю несколько программ после перезагрузки они снова есть, или же добавлю, а они исчезают после перезагрузки.
Точно не виртуальная))